# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘ocr_server’: File exists

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, mkdir, file-exists

I want to build a simple script in Python that will help us detect characters from images and expose this through a Flask application for a more convenient interaction medium.

I'm using PyTesseract to setup Simple Python Optical Character Recognition
I'm setting up the environment and in a process I got stuck at this step

I've installed pipenv using "$ pip install pipenv" command and after this unable to execute cd ocr_server, please help, Thanks in advance

swap@swap-HP-EliteBook-8470p:~/Downloads$ mkdir ocr_server && cd ocr_server && pipenv install --three
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘ocr_server’: File exists

Comment: The directory already exists so you cannot create it. You should be able to do `cd ocr_server` then `pipenv install --three`.